# Manwha in which the protagonist died from an illness in the hospital, then she was reincarnated into a novel she was reading

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I remember it being a typical reincarnation romance story but what set it apart was that *the protagonist was a young girl who died from illness in a hospital before being reincarnated into a novel* she was reading at the time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

***[The Tyrant's Only Perfumer](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5521i9d/the-tyrant-s-only-perfumer)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> **A young woman sick with an incurable illness closes her eyes for the last time, only to wake up as Ariel Winston, an antagonist of the novel she had loved reading before her death.** Knowing that death lies before her if she continues down the path the real Ariel has been going towards, she quickly breaks up with Duke Cedric Evans, who is not only the protagonist of the novel, but a man who is cursed with a condition which causes him to become bloodthirsty when he does not smell a specific scent constantly. However, Cedric, who had been forced to date Ariel due to her status as his personal perfumer, suddenly seems reluctant to distance himself from her. Just what is wrong with this man, and how will this change the events of the novel? Will Ariel be able to live the life she wants?

[image] [image]