# reincarnation manhwa where the mc reincarnate into a sick girl

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The manhwa I'm looking for has a girl who reincarnated in a novel she read in her past life if I'm not mistaken, and she's a villain and the daughter of a noble, she has a disease that has no cure and she's going to die, she has a whole stock of medicinal herbs and decides to donate it since she knows she is going to die, there are also some crazy princes who kind of kill the orphaned children who have powers, and there are some characters who are like the protagonists and she decides to help them to prevent the princes kill these children, one of them even hands her a stick that is a kind of communicator for them to talk to each other

Comment: *[Ascendance of a Bookworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascendance_of_a_Bookworm)?*

Comment: *[I Became the Daughter-in-Law of the Villain Because I'm Terminally Ill!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264845/manwha-where-a-girl-is-reborn-and-knows-shes-supposed-to-die-of-an-illness-in-f)?*

Comment: *[The Tyrant's Only Perfumer...?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264649/manwha-in-which-the-protagonist-died-from-an-illness-in-the-hospital-then-she-w)*

Comment: *[When the Villainess is in Love](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/when-the-villainess-is-in-love)?*

Answer (score -1):

[*Please Obsess Over Me*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/please-obsess-over-me)

[image: Cover image for Please Obsess Over Me]

> Just before Princess Arabella Strovna’s 24th birthday, she and the entire imperial family die at the hands of the rebel army. Thanks to a magical blessing, though, she wakes up and she’s… 20 again? Trapped in a loop of rebirth, Arabella continues to repeat the same four years, only to be killed every time. To break the cycle, she must befriend her own murderers, the three rebel leaders. But as she gains their trust, Arabella realizes that they may not be the true villains of this tale…

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how this matches the details provided in the question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Instead of just posting a link, please include details from the page you're linking to in case the link goes away someday.

Comment: It sounds like there's maybe 1 plot point that this matches, TBF.